# JSON binding for BPEL service in WSO2BPS

Tags: json, wso2, bpel

I would like to create a BPEL service in WSO2BPEL that has a JSON binding - so it get's started when a JSON string is sent to it. 
I know I can create an API facade using WSO2ESB, but it would be nice to circumvent that and have BPS receive the JSON string directly. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by WSO2 BPS, because WS-BPEL 2.0 is purely based on SOAP, WSDL, XML etc.[1]. As you mentioned you can achieve this by exposing API facade using WSO2ESB.

eg.  JSON <-> WSO2 ESB API <-> SOAP/XML <-> WSO2 BPS

[1] - http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/OS/wsbpel-v2.0-OS.html